# Move an android emulator snapshot to another computer

Tags: android, emulation, snapshot

So, I need to make one snapshot that can be used by multiple people/across multiple computers. I'm doing some testing, and a lot of things need to be setup to test one thing. It takes a while to set things up, and I'd like to be able to just create one avd and let several people use it. I thought I could do this by making one and then taking a snapshot, but no matter what I do I just can't get that to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to make a snapshot(a picture) available to everyone in your team? Email? Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to distribute:

- the file $HOME/.android/avd/< avdname >.ini
- some files from directory $HOME/.android/avd/< avdname >: config.ini, *.img

When deploying on a new computer, just fix absolute path in < avdname >.ini file.