# Reuse AVD snapshot

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, snapshot

After saving an emulator snapshot I would like to reuse the snapshot across multiple AVD's.

According to the documentation when saving a snapshot it is stored in the directory ~/.android/avd/<avd_name>.avd/snapshots and the default snapstorage is snapshots.img.

My plan was to copy both the snapshots.img file and the snapshot directory into a different AVD folder but while I do see the snapshot files being created, for the life of me, I can't find the location of the snapshots.img file.

Does anyone know where this file is located? Or, if I'm going around this the wrong way, can someone shed some light on the right way?

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731254/move-an-android-emulator-snapshot-to-another-computer

Comment: @user3875913 The answer there isn't detailed enough. Ideally, I would like to be able to run multiple emulators with the same snapshot and different skins.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mac OS.

I just saved a snapshot. My snapshot was saved to:

```
/Users/<myusername>/.android/avd/<mydevicename>.avd/snapshots
```

There were two sub folders:

`default_boot` : this folder contained a ram.img file

`snap_2020-08-22_09-59-33` : this folder did not contain any img files.

Comment: Thanks for this but did you manage to use the same snapshot on a different emulator?